# Send interrupt to cpu as keyboard do?

Tags: c++, c, usb, interrupt

Is it possible to simulate hardware interrupts somehow from user program?
I've seen this question posted many times, but always not answered.

I want to know about low-level interrupts (for example simulate situation when key pressed on keyboard, so that keyboard driver would interrupt interrupt).

High level events and APIs are outside scope, and question is rather theoretical than practical (to prevent "why" discussions :)

Comment: Well, you could modify the OS kernel so that you can call the interrupt *handlers* manually from userspace.

Comment: If you can access the interrupt vectors, you should be able to find where the interrupt is handled, and call there.  You'll need to have privileged user rights, of course, and maybe write a bit of assembler.

Comment: on intel x86 machines yes.  on others, i don't know. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)  you need to have the right priv to be able to do that.

Comment: What operating system are we talking about here? Neither Windows, MacOS or Linux will allow this under any circumstances other than writing your own driver [and even in your own driver, it would be rather hard].

Comment: @us2012, I don't have kernel source

Comment: I would point out that using "INT" instruction on x86 _may_ work like an interrupt, but it's sometimes not [e.g NMI].

Comment: there are drivers out there that can get your user program code into ring 0 for windows and linux. not sure about mac.

Comment: So basically even if I call INT, it will be refused?

Comment: @Aniket: Get it. Problem solved.

Comment: Even if you managed to call the correct interrupt handler, it would then attempt to extract a keycode from the keyboard interface hardware.  There would be no keycode available and I don't know what would happen then - the handler may signal a null char to the kernel or coredump/BSOD.    I would not like to try to spoof keyboard input like this.  Also, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

On an x86 CPU (for one example) there's an `int` instruction that generates an interrupt. Once the interrupt is generated, the CPU won't necessarily<sup>1</sup> distinguish between an interrupt generated by hardware and one generated by software. For one example, in the original PC BIOS, IBM chose an interrupt that would cause the print-screen command to execute. The interrupt they chose (interrupt 5) was one that wasn't then in use, but which Intel had said was reserved for future use. Intel eventually did put that interrupt to use -- in the 286 they added a `bound` instruction that checks that a value is within bounds, and generates an interrupt if it's not. The `bound` instruction is essentially never used though, because it generates interrupt 5 if a value is out of bounds. This means (if you're running something like MS-DOS that allows it) executing the `bound` instruction with a value that's out of bounds will print the screen.

On a modern OS, however, this won't generally be allowed. All generation and handling of interrupts happens in the kernel. The hardware had 4 levels of protection ("rings") and support for specifying the ring at which the `int` instruction can be executed. If you try to execute it from code running at ring 3, it won't execute directly -- instead, execution will switch to the OS kernel, which can treat it as it chooses.

This allows (for example) Windows to emulate MS-DOS, so MS-DOS programs (which *do* use the `int` instruction) can execute in a virtual machine, with virtualized input and output, so even though they "think" they're working directly with the keyboard and screen hardware, they're actually using emulations of them provided by software.

For "native" programs, however, using most `int` instructions (i.e. any but a tiny number of interrupts intended for communication with the kernel) will simply result in the program being shut down.

So, bottom line: yes, the hardware supports it -- but the hardware also supports prohibiting it, and nearly every modern OS does exactly that, at least for most code outside the OS kernel itself.

---

1. Though, with typical hardware, the interrupt handler can read data from the programmable interrupt controller (PIC) chip that will tell it whether the interrupt came through the PIC (i.e., hardware interrupt) or not (software interrupt). Most hardware also supports at least a few interrupts that can be generated only by hardware, such as NMI on the x86. These are usually reserved for fairly narrow uses though (e.g., NMI on a PC is normally used for things like memory parity errors).

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask one more related question, if there any low level  opportunity to simulate HID devices events? For example on OS X there is `CGEventPost`, but is it possible to make event on lower level somehow?

Comment: @dig: Depending on how low-level you want, you might be able to use `SendInput`, `keybd_event`, `mouse_event`, or (if you want to go really low level) a device driver that synthesizes input.